# error installing rinku gem as part of shapado 'rinku_autolink should return a value'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to install shapado (www.shapado.com) on Max OSX 10.8.2. One of the gems, Rinku, brings the following error when trying to install:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling autolink.c
compiling buffer.c
compiling rinku.c
rinku.c:165:3: error: non-void function 'rinku_autolink' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
            return;
            ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [rinku.o] Error 1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Any thoughts would be excellent!

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue

```
/Users/adamo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling autolink.c
make: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [autolink.o] Error 1
```

I have homebrew and I did:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install apple-gcc42
```

and then I was able to do `bundle install` with no errors. I hope it solves your issue too.